# Is it possible to start my angular SPA only after the dotnet api gets initialized in my launch.json file?

Tags: angular, .net-core, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When debugging in Visual Studio Code, is it possible to start my Angular SPA only after my dotnet API has initialized in my compound config statement?

My compound config below starts both (SPA and Dotnet) together, but in some cases, not all, the SPA starts up and finishes initializing before the dotnet API initializes and the SPA makes a call immediately to the db in the API on the home page. So in the cases where the SPA in done initializing but the API hasn't finished initializing I see an error like this below.
So I have to refresh the browser once or twice until the dotnet API finishes initializing first.

It seems like the initialization of the two projects when debugging and which one finishes first is completely random?

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED [http://localhost:5001/api/matter/options]

Here is my compound config:

```js
"compounds": [{
  "name": "Server/Client",
  "configurations": ["Dotnet", "Chrome"]
}],
"configurations": [{
  "name": "Chrome",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:4200",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/Auto2-SPA"
}, {
  "name": "Dotnet",
  "type": "coreclr",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "build",
  // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Auto2.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/Auto2.API.dll",
  "args": [],
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Auto2.API",
  "stopAtEntry": false,
  // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser

  "env": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "sourceFileMap": {
    "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
  }
}]
```

Comment: This is just while you are developing application, right? I mean you dont need this in prod build?

Comment: Correct. Once it's running on the prod server I'm ok. This is just for debugging!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **APP_INITIALIZER**, a function that is invoked as soon as the application is started and does not initialize the application until it is completed.

For example, you could ping your APIs and see if they are ready, if they are not, repeat the ping N times until a timeout.

I did a stackblitz to explain to you more or less how it works, even if it has many redundant things. Since I have to simulate pinging the API, I had to insert different timeouts on the calls to make them look at least realistic.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rnuwn9

I hope I understood what you needed

Comment: So basically what you're saying is that I should run your connectionTest() in my home page on my init method, which calls the controller, until I get a response, then when I get a ping response back from the connectionTest, then call to my controller to load the data?

Comment: yes, I also use this technique in one of my applications because I had the same problem as you.

Comment: But not in your home Page, APP_INITIALIZER, like you can see in the example Is a build in injection token provide by Angular

Comment: just curious, do you think your solution is better then the other proposed solution?

Comment: I think this is a native solution compared to the other solution, but I leave you the choice of who is better according to your needs.
I just hope I've been helpful.

Comment: quick question - can you tell me how your solution pings the API? Doesn't it need to have the url or address or something?

Comment: If you didn't have it, you will generate an exception and then after n seconds you will retry until it is ready.

Comment: Hi Francesco. Maybe you misunderstood my question. In your solution, I don't see any url being used. So when you explain that your solution pings the API until it gets a response, I assume that it needs to know the url/address of the API? Or does it not work that way?

Comment: I really am not following you, if the application starts and calls any function that points to your server (the application gives you an error because the server has not yet started) you can call that function until the server is started ?

Comment: ok I'll rephrase. I don't really understand your stackblitz code..What does the ping method do? Does it ping the API? And if so, doesn't it need an address?

Answer (score 0):

There is a npm package called [wait-on](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-on). This plugin waits for certain action to be completed and then gives control back to the next line of execution.

What you can do, suppose you have some open endpoint (endpoint without security), you can configure this before starting your angular app so that whenever the back-end is ready then and then only front-end end will be compiled and executed.

You can configure this is `package.json`.

1. `npm install -g wait-on`
2. modify `start` script as follows (replace `http://localhost:8000/foo` with your endpoint)

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "wait-on http://localhost:8000/foo && ng serve",
  ...
```

After this when you start the angular app with `npm start`, it will wait for endpoint and start only when endpoint is available.

Comment: not sure if it makes a difference but I already have ng serve running when I start the debugger?

Comment: So  front end is running, and in that running state if backend restarts, then you want to wait for backend to complete its startup, is it?

Comment: I believe that is correct. I have ng serve running, then I start the bebugger that starts dotnet and open the browser. As soon as I start the debugger I get an exception that says the connection is refused, which I believe is because my app is trying to make a call on the home page to connect to the db and fetch some data, but can't because dotnet hasn't finished loading by the debugger.

Comment: I think you need to poll to backend for availability while in `dev`. I ll create stakblitz to show what I mean by this.

Comment: Are you fine with creating some dummy api in your .net application? e.g. `http://localhost:8080/api/test`.

Comment: possibly, but that doesn't seem like a reasonable solution, so I wouldn't award you the points.